# Google Search Appliance wildcard character support

Tags: search-engine, google-search-appliance

Does Google Search Appliance support wildcard characters in the query string. If no, is there any way I can fetch all the result set through my query?

Answer (score 0):

The GSA does not support wildcarding.  An option can be to[N-Gram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) the fields or content that you want wildcarded.  This would be achieved in your feeder or pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If waiting and upgrading the gsa software to v 7.2,.coming mid December is an option you will have wild card search built in.

Otherwise you have to dig deeper. A possible option is a document filter. If you are interested in that option I might be able to help.

I have developed such a document filter.

Answer (score 0):

GSA software 7.4 has wildcard search built in. From [documentation](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/74/gsa_doc_set/quick_start/quick_start_se.html#1091590):

**Enabling Wildcard Search**

Wildcard search is a feature that enables your users to search by entering a word pattern rather than the exact spelling of a term. The search appliance supports two wildcard operators:

- *--Matches zero or more characters
- ?--Matches exactly 1 character

Using wildcards can simplify queries for long names, technical data, pharmaceutical information, or strings where the exact spelling varies or is unknown. A user can search for all words starting with a particular pattern, ending with a particular pattern, or having a particular substring pattern.

By default, wildcard indexing is disabled for your search appliance. You can enable or disable wildcard indexing by using the Index > Index Settings page. You can disable or enable wildcard search for one or more front ends by using the Filters tab of the Search > Search Features > Front Ends page.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get all indexed items from a collection is to use a query that will match every indexed record, e.g., supposing you're indexing some set of URLs from subdomain.companyname.com, just query for "companyname", with the "&num=1000&filter=0" query string parameters.